# How to manipulate/stylize the edges of shadows?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes, shadows, shader-nodes

I am trying to manipulate/stylize the edges of shadows. What I mean by that is that I would like to split the transition of a shadow to non shadow area into different colours like so
[image: how it is]
[image: how I want it to be]

Is either of this possible procedurally without hand painting it? I did the second version in photoshop. I've tried using the shader to rgb node with color ramps to get shadows that are slightly offset and then color them differently but it doesn't really work. Is there a way to do it? Possibly in compositing?

Answer (score 0):

This only works in Cycles renderer, but you can probably get somewhere by messing around with a setup like this. Using a *Light Path* node you can change the color of a shadow, and then probably through compositing/manipulating the material of the ground plane you could get close to the result you're looking for.
[image]